# Temperature sensor via rs232 windows 7

Tags: serial-port

I connected a temperature sensor (that send data by text) to the computer via RS232 with W7.

If I open my notepad, I do not receive anything data. 
Instead, when I connect it to the old XP, it show me the data.

I need to configure W7 in a particular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a cmd prompt and type

```
type com1:
```

Use ctrl-c to terminate

Answer (score 2):

You need to use hyperterminal and configure the COM port correctly...
This link will help you        [enter link description here](http://www.doztech.net/howto/download-hyperterminal-for-windows-7-and-install-it/)